# Convert javascript Object array to just array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

So I've created a giant object, that goes through a database table and collects all the rows with appropriate column names like so (sx is a string that is outputted into javascript):

```
if (i == 0)
{
   sx += "SearchAutocomplete['"+ s.Key + "'] = {};";
}
sx += "SearchAutocomplete['" + s.Key + "'][" + i + "] = '" + s.Value + "';";
```

(the above is C# code but the error is the javascript part).

My goal is to use this giant object to put it inside autocomplete() function of JQuery UI, based on the column name...

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

```
htmltable += sx + "$('#mySearchBox').autocomplete({" +
                "source: jQuery.makeArray(SearchAutocomplete['" + columnName + "'])" +
                "});"
```

I tried using jQuery.makeArray, but no matter what I try, it doesn't recognize SearchAutocomplete['columnName'] as an array of values.

The autocomplete doesn't work.

I'm guessing the solution is to somehow loop through and convert the object back into an array maybe. But is there an easier way?

**Attempt to fix #1:**

```
if(list_fields.ContainsKey(s.Key)){
   if (i == 0)
   {
      sx += "SearchAutocomplete['"+ s.Key + "'] = [];";
   }
   sx += "SearchAutocomplete['" + s.Key + "'].push('" + s.Value + "');";
 }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but sx is a string in JavaScript, correct? Wouldn't you need to split the string into a JavaScript array object? You would probably need to use a combination of .split and a more complex regex to match on.

Comment: @Mark: `sx` is a string, but I'm guessing it's just part of a dynamically generated chunk of JS that Dexter is going to dump into a response. It should look correct to the browser.

Comment: The array would have to look like an Array literal I believe. `[{s.Key: s.Value},{...}]` and not a string of array key value assignments.

Comment: No it works, there's no javascript error in web console. The code comes out good in the javascript. Just when you try to insert into source: of autocomplete, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this change:

```
//Outside your loop:
sx += "SearchAutocomplete['" + s.Key + "'] = [];";
//... Inside your loop:
sx += "SearchAutocomplete['" + s.Key + "'].push('" + s.Value + "');";
```

That way, `SearchAutocomplete[columnName]` is a native array to start.

Comment: Hey, I tried that now, before I had = {}; which is an object. But it still isn't working with autocomplete. Also no javascript errors. Please see "Attempt to fix #1" above.

Comment: I also removed jQuery.MakeArray()

Comment: Somehow I made a working simplified example, but it works there and not here. http://jsbin.com/aligik/1   <--- test and edit javascript here. I'm so confused, how does it work there but not on mine? Is it because I have jqueryui_autocomplete_min instead of jqueryui_min ??

Comment: What the..it works now... I dunno, maybe it was cached and your solution now works.